# Using a list for x and y axis in plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I have a Python list that I want to use to chart a line chart in Plotly.
The list contains accidents in each week of the year. So for instance list[5]=12 would indicate that in week 5 of 2020, there were 12 accidents.
I want to draw a line chart showing the trend of accidents in 2020.

The full list split into two lists is as follows:

```
x axis [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53]
y axis [0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
```

If I enumerate the single list it is as follows:

```
for e,i in enumerate(my_list):
    print(f"e->{e}, i->{i}")
    e->0, i->0
    e->1, i->0
    e->2, i->0
    e->3, i->2
    e->4, i->3
    e->5, i->4
    e->6, i->2
    e->7, i->3
    e->8, i->2
    e->9, i->2
    e->10, i->6
    e->11, i->4
    e->12, i->2
    e->13, i->1
    e->14, i->2
    e->15, i->1
    e->16, i->1
    e->17, i->3
    e->18, i->1
    e->19, i->0
    e->20, i->0
    e->21, i->0
    e->22, i->0
    e->23, i->0
    e->24, i->0
    e->25, i->0
    e->26, i->0
    e->27, i->0
    e->28, i->0
    e->29, i->0
    e->30, i->0
    e->31, i->0
    e->32, i->0
    e->33, i->0
    e->34, i->0
    e->35, i->0
    e->36, i->0
    e->37, i->0
    e->38, i->0
    e->39, i->0
    e->40, i->0
    e->41, i->0
    e->42, i->0
    e->43, i->0
    e->44, i->0
    e->45, i->0
    e->46, i->0
    e->47, i->0
    e->48, i->0
    e->49, i->0
    e->50, i->0
    e->51, i->0
    e->52, i->0
    e->53, i->0
```

The index of the list will be X axis and the value will be the Y axis.
Normally what I do is use two lists as follows:

```
# load the x and y axis
my_figure = px.line(x=x_list, y=y_list, title="Testing")
                       

# now draw the line chart
dcc.Graph(id='my_figure', figure=my_figure),
```

However, in this case I only have one list, and I want to avoid copying the index value into a 2nd list. How can I use the single list with Plotly to draw a line chart?

Comment: could you provide your data so we can get a better understanding of what your trying to accomplish, and what data you are using

Comment: I updated the question with the data, thanks!

Comment: You have provided the actual data, the actual list which you are using is what would be useful in helping solve your problem. So could you provide the actual list?

Comment: I added both lists, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dataframe and then try plotting with that dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_data':x_list, 'y_data':y_list})

px.line(df, x='x_data', y='y_data', title="Testing")
```

`px.line(df, y='y_data', title="Testing")` also works in this case

Comment: I have one list, you are listing two lists in your example. I want to use the index of my single list as x_data and the values as the y_data.